# How to remove all the spec files from existing Angular cli project

Tags: angular

I am currently working with angular cli project. I see the spec file generated for every component, services and I want to remove all this spec files from this existing project.

Comment: Any specific reason to remove spec file in  application ?

Answer (score 17):

Deleting them from an existing project depends on your OS. If it is a Unix based system you could do something like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.spec.ts' -delete
```

This would remove all files which end in `spec.ts` recursively starting in your current directory.

To prevent these files from being generated again use the `--skipTests` flag when generating components, providers, whatever:

```
ng g s my-service --skipTests
```

This will generate a service `my-service` without any spec files.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions it's `--skip-tests`
 [ng generate](https://angular.io/cli/generate)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows you can use this: `del /s /q *.spec.ts`